# Can a target variable in a supervised machine learning task be an array for a specific object?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, target

Can a target variable in a supervised machine learning task be an array for a specific object?
I'm planning to build a machine learning model for a petroleum engineering task - which is to build a permeability map having an "input". In fact I should be able to get a map (which is 2d array) as output. Is it possible to have such a map in target variable to train a model?

Input:

[image: input]

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: yes, its possible. the only constraint for the output really is that the shape of the output needs to stay fixed.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Thats even not a limit. You can use [Fully Convolutional Networks (FCNs)](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf) and apply on arbitrary size. You can also use an older approach and use patches instead. The only thing is it required adjusting the scales and resolutions so the first layer will be applied on a correct scaled image.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh,@mr_mo could you please give a practical example of how data is composed so that I could visualize what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. 
[U-net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) is one possible solution for your task.  Or maybe you may try to use generative models like [Pixel CNN](https://github.com/openai/pixel-cnn).